# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shareaspetto.com/share/updateprofile.php?name=%@&gender=%@&email=%@&about_us=%@&id=%@&image=%@", nameString, genderString, emailString, aboutusString, idString, imgNameString];
NSLog(@"urlString = %@", urlString);
while ([urlString rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
}    
NSString *rplyString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

The warning `Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSString *'` occurs when I compile the above code.

Comment: wt is your warnig ??? please put proper code

Comment: Where is your warning exactly? Also, I'm confused about the last line. Why pass a string to a NSURL only to pass that NSURL to an NSString method. Why not just `NSString *rplyString = urlString`?

Comment: @Th3Cuber because then `rplyString` would be the same as `urlString`, and it **would not** contain the data located at the URL described by `urlString`.

Comment: Also, this is a **horrible** way of URL-escaping a string. Try `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()`.

Comment: @NishantShah What line is your warning on?

Answer (score 1):

Covert String with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shareaspetto.com/share/updateprofile.php?name=%@&gender=%@&email=%@&about_us=%@&id=%@&image=%@", nameString, genderString, emailString, aboutusString, idString, imgNameString];
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSLog(@"urlString = %@", urlString);
while ([urlString rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
}

NSString *rplyString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```